# What happens once function inside a Controller gets called?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller

I have a function, lets say that it does some trivial calculation. The `Controller` which has this function is around `5000` lines long (Not written by me).

Now, when I call a function which has trivial calculation. Does the server has to create an `Object` of this really large file and then run my function?

Does every request create new `Object` of my `Controller` or once it's created it stays there for given `session`.

**PS** : I am thinking of breaking down this code, but just wanted to know whether it will give me an advantage in performance.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what the code looks like? For every view, are you calling the function by instantiating a new object? Are you thinking of using a static functions, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Refactoring` is an important aspect of continuously trying to make your code better. You should not look only at `performance enhancement` as an incentive, `code maintainability` is also an important factor. A controller function having 5k lines is definitely a candidate for refactoring.

To answer your original question - whether a controller object is re-instantiated on every request depends on how the framework has been designed, more often than not core framework objects get instantiated once and is referred to as and when needed.